# How to interpret the response from OpenSSL?

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, openssl, certificate, aws-iot

So in the [AWS IoT tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-dg.pdf) I get this:

[image]

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/certs $ openssl s_client -connect iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 -CAfile root-CA.pem -cert certificate.pem.crt  -key private.pem.key
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Washington, L = Seattle, O = "Amazon.com, Inc.", CN = iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
 1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
---
Server certificate
STUFFHERE
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3264 bytes and written 415 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: FC6ABAE41818994E5D7B6AE83DCE0F717396D7F5314CFB096CD967489A136CCA
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: STUFFHERE
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 10800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - d5 b9 92 64 2c 92 37 2c-79 c2 68 04 28 ef f4 d7   ...d,.7,y.h.(...
    0010 - e1 31 dc 7e 80 51 a8 ef-da ab 0f 60 7e 5b 1d 52   .1.~.Q.....`~[.R
    0020 - b1 03 06 52 ac 8b 32 12-54 1f 86 72 f4 a7 2b f3   ...R..2.T..r..+.
    0030 - ba 3b f8 91 a6 fc ce 53-d2 0c d9 96 75 a2 4c f1   .;.....S....u.L.
    0040 - 31 bd f4 84 f2 c6 b8 51-06 8c 36 22 12 b3 82 99   1......Q..6"....
    0050 - b6 13 b9 f8 fa 54 e4 0d-eb 01 b6 c4 82 b2 1b 88   .....T..........
    0060 - c6 af 3b 54 58 83 77 4b-69 b2 b1 8c cb 0a 7c 81   ..;TX.wKi.....|.
    0070 - 70 a9 d5 d2 fd f8 3b 21-e3 8e b2 e6 c4 83 f9 af   p.....;!........
    0080 - bc 3f 8e fa 33 ae 28 7b-be e6 8d 6b aa 96 4e 56   .?..3.({...k..NV
    0090 - 12 6f b3 9d bc b5 53 fa-23 3c 79 5b 41 a1 ae 5a   .o....S.#<y[A..Z

    Start Time: 1457306705
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
closed
```

I have the followings in the ~/certs folder:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/certs $ ls
certificate.pem.crt  private.pem.key  public.pem.key  root-CA.pem
```

[image]

Comment: What is it you are trying to validate with OpenSSL? Are you unable to open a connection to AWS IoT with your certificate in an MQTT client?

Be sure to use the correct AWS region when inputting endpoints. In this case, I see you are using the us-west-2 (Oregon) region in the AWS console (and I'm assuming your certificate is generated in that region), but you are trying to validate it against the us-east-1 (N. Virginia) region. Certificates are specific to the region they were created.

Comment: That is just a print in cmdline.js (I have actually changed the actually value to us-west2) it is weird the tutorial is not consistent somehow as I am getting a similar error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834370/aws-iot-private-pem-key-doesnt-exist

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: ^That is part of the development! The tutorial for app dev in AWS IoT had missing part so I am just helping others who will have the same question in the future! There's lots of trivial questions in SO and then you come and close my question which will be helpful to others @jww