# AWS IoT private.pem.key doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, pem, aws-iot

When I am trying to run the following node.js example from AWS IoT I get this error(following [this tutorial](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/blob/master/README.md)):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/examples $ node device-example.js -g

private.pem.key doesn't exist (--help for usage)
```

However I have the private.pem.key in `~/certs` folder as requested by the tutorial.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/examples $ vi device-example.js 
pi@raspberrypi:~/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/examples $ ls ~/certs/private.pem.key 
/home/pi/certs/private.pem.key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device-example.js program is designed to be run in pairs; each process communicates with the other through the AWS IoT platform.  You'll need to start another copy of the program (it can be on another host) in order to see them communicating.  More information about running the example programs can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#programs).  Thanks for using AWS IoT.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by giving the paths like the following: `pi@raspberrypi:~/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/examples $ node device-example.js --aws-region=us-west-2 --certificate-dir=/home/pi/certs --test-mode=2`

Comment: On a sidenote, should it just get stuck at the "connect" message? pi@raspberrypi:~/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/examples $ node device-example.js --aws-region=us-west-2 --certificate-dir=/home/pi/certs --test-mode=2
connect

Comment: I am stuck at message attempting new mqtt connection. Not going ahead of it. anything wrong?